# Hide button when entering data in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to hide a button after the user registers their profile.

In the database, I have the one to one relation between Profile and User.

This is the button:

```
@if ()
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" href="{{ route('profile.create') }}"><div>Sube tus datos</div></a>
    </div>
@else
@endif
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to make it check if it already has a profile and hide the button.

I would appreciate some advice or recommendation.

Comment: `@if(!auth()->user()->profile)` maybe? This assumes that there's a logged in `User`. Also, you don't need an empty `@else` block, just `@if() ... @endif`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already add a relation to the profile in the `User` model. If not first add the relation.

After that add this code in User model in order to check if the one-one relation exists. This code will return true if the user has relation to profile.

```
public function isProfileComplete()
{
    return $this->profile()->exists();
}
```

Check in blade :

```
@if (!auth()->user()->isProfileComplete())
<div class="col-md-2">
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" href="{{ route('profile.create') }}"><div>Sube tus datos</div></a>
</div>
@else
@endif
```